# Unable to push docker image on registry using Jenkinsfile

Tags: docker, jenkins, openshift

I am trying to push my image through Jenkinsfile on repository but when I do that I am facing below error.

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://mydockerregistryurl/v1/users/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I have found many articles about this but did not understand any of this.

Can anyone try to help me?

Below is my jenkinsfile.

```
#!groovy

pipeline {
  agent {
    node {
      label 'otd-agent'
    }
  }
  stages{
    stage('Test Stage'){
      steps{
          sh 'mvn clean test'
      }
    }
    stage('SonarQube Analysis'){
      steps{
        withSonarQubeEnv('otd-sonar') {
          sh 'mvn sonar:sonar'
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Package Stage'){
      steps{
        sh 'mvn clean package'
      }
    }
    stage('Building Docker image') {
      steps{
        script {
          sh 'docker build . -t jagathe-spike'
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Deploy Docker Image') {
      steps{
        script {
          sh 'docker login -u username -p password docker-registry-default'
          sh 'docker push docker-registry-default/otd-agathe'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If target registry `docker-registry-default` is running on `OpenShift`, you should deploy the `OCP` `CA` certificate which download from `OCP` on your Jenkins host.
Refer [Installing a certificate authority certificate for external registries](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.10/day_two_guide/docker_tasks.html#day-two-managing-docker-certs-installing-a-cert-authority) for more details.

For instance,

- Download CA certificate from your OCP.

```
jenkins ~# scp root@master1.ocp.example.com:/etc/origin/master/ca.crt \
           /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/ocp-ca.crt
```

- Execuste update-ca-trust for registering the CA.

```
jenkins ~# update-ca-trust extract
```

- Copy the CA to `/etc/docker/certs.d` as follows.(${} is placeholder, you should replace it properly with your information)

```
jenkins ~# cp /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/ocp-ca.crt \
           /etc/docker/certs.d/${docker-registry-default}:${PORT}
```

- Restart docker service for reloading

```
jenkins ~# systemctl restart docker.service
```

I hope it help you.